# Toggle DOM elements depending on which if statement is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JavaScript project which greets you differently depending 
on the time of day it is in real time.

For example, if hours is under 12 it will say good morning. But I'm missing one thing which I have no idea how to add.

I want a button and possibly different divs to appear depending on which 
if / if else statement is executed. For example if it is morning, I'm trying to make a "Brew Coffee" button appear, "Turn on TV" if it is afternoon etc.

The problem is I have no idea how to execute this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting | Test</title>
</head>
<body align="center">

<style>

</style>

<script>

var Name = prompt("Hello! What is your name?");

var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
var hourAd = hour - 12;


if(hour < 12){ //target if statement to toggle button
   document.write("Good Morning , " + Name + "." +
                   "<br /> It is currently " +
                    hour + ":" + min + " Am" );
                    //button code
}

else if(hour > 12){
        document.write("Good Afternoon , " + Name + "." +
        "<br /> It is currently " +
        hourAd + ":" + min + " Pm" );
}

else if(hour > 19){
        document.write("Good Evening , " + Name + "." +
        "<br /> It is currently " +
        hourAd + ":" + min + " Pm " );
}
</script>

<!--execute when if statement is true-->
<button id="coffee">Brew Coffee</button>
<button id="tv">Turn on TV</button>
<button id="dinner">Let's make dinner</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to hide all div by using `style="display:none"` and `document.getElementById("your display id").style.display = "block";` you can overview working example as below :

```js
var Name = prompt("Hello! What is your name?");

var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();
var hourAd = hour - 12;


if(hour < 12){ //target if statement to toggle button
   document.write("Good Morning , " + Name + "." +
                   "<br /> It is currently " +
                    hour + ":" + min + " Am" );
                    //button code
  document.getElementById("coffee").style.display = "block";                  
}

else if(hour > 12){
        document.write("Good Afternoon , " + Name + "." +
        "<br /> It is currently " +
        hourAd + ":" + min + " Pm" );
        document.getElementById("tv").style.display = "block"; 
}

else if(hour > 19){
        document.write("Good Evening , " + Name + "." +
        "<br /> It is currently " +
        hourAd + ":" + min + " Pm " );
        document.getElementById("dinner").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting | Test</title>
</head>
<body align="center">

<style>

</style>


<!--execute when if statement is true-->
<button id="coffee" style="display:none">Brew Coffee</button>
<button id="tv" style="display:none">Turn on TV</button>
<button id="dinner" style="display:none">Let's make dinner</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean simple jquery/javascript can do it; just add or remove classes or css.
Maybe go for display:none; css depending on time

jquery example (change button color on click)

```js
    $( "button#myBtnID" ).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "mycss_class" );
    });
    //you can do addClass() or removeClass() too; see jquery api
```

```css
.mycss_class {
    color: white;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="myBtnID"> click me to change css class</button>
```